# What is the difference and use of newline argument and line terminator argument in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, functional-programming, arguments, file-handling

I was working with CSV file objects when I came across the **line terminator dialect** in a CSV writer object...

Firstly, what is its purpose? I don't exactly understand what it does, or what happens when it's not used.

Second, I came across some examples using the `newline` argument when getting the file object (not the CSV writer object). What is its purpose or use? How is it different from the `lineterminator` argument?

I have two snippets of my code using either of these arguments below, and both work exactly the same. I don't completely understand what the Python documentation says about dialects and these two arguments.

**NOTE: The difference when none of the arguments are used, is only when writing to a file (this is part of a file handling function). The code shows the reading bit (apologies for the error).

**Using the `lineterminator` argument:**

```
# Handles reading and modifying CSV files
def FileHandler(targetFile, mode, data=[]):
    content = []

    with open(targetFile, mode) as file:
        file_reader = csv.reader(file, lineterminator="\n")
        for line in file_reader:
            content.append(line)

        num_of_lines = len(content)
        file.close()
        return content, num_of_lines
```

**Using the `newline` argument:**

```
# Handles reading and modifying CSV files
def FileHandler(targetFile, mode, data=[]):
    content = []

    with open(targetFile, mode, newline="\n") as file:
        file_reader = csv.reader(file)
        for line in file_reader:
            content.append(line)

        num_of_lines = len(content)
        file.close()
        return content, num_of_lines
```

Comment: Post code as code-formatted text, not as image links. Also, that's not a "lineterminator dialect", and you could have just looked at the docs.

Comment: Also, [`reader` ignores `lineterminator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator), so that code doesn't mean what the author wanted it to mean.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently having to use my phone and don't have the code in text. Thus the link to the images. As I have clearly mentioned, I didn't understand what the docs meant. Hence I posted it on here.

Comment: This is part of a file handler function which has the reader and writer. I had taken the reader snip by mistake, apologies. The difference is only when I write to a file. So could you elaborate on its function and differences?

Answer (score 4):

As the [`csv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) says:

> **Dialect.lineterminator** 
> The string used to terminate lines produced by the writer. It defaults to `'\r\n'`.

> Note: The reader is hard-coded to recognise either `'\r'` or `'\n'` as end-of-line, and ignores `lineterminator`. This behavior may change in the future.

It specifies the characters used for the end of each row written to the CSV.  Linux files usually have a linefeed only (`\n`) and Windows files usually have a carriage return plus linefeed (`\r\n`).

Since the `csv` module writes its own line endings, the file opened for use with `reader` and `writer` must be opened with `newline=''`.  This is also explained in the documentation, which also has the following footnote:

> **Footnotes**

> [1] If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the `csv` module does its own (universal) newline handling.

In the [open()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open) documentation:

> `newline` controls how universal newlines mode works (it only applies to text mode). It can be `None`, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and `'\r\n'`. It works as follows:

> - When reading input from the stream, if `newline` is `None`, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in `'\n'`, `'\r'`, or `'\r\n'`, and these are translated into `'\n'` before being returned to the caller. If it is `''`, universal newlines mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to the caller untranslated. If it has any of the other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.

> - When writing output to the stream, if `newline` is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, `os.linesep`. If newline is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If newline is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the documentation for the open() built-in function. I also did some more testing. So according to the doc for open(), if newline=' '  it should return the line endings untranslated. But when i use the function with open("file.csv", newline=' ') and get each row given by csv.reader("file.csv"), and check one of its value with another value (such as: user0 == user0\r\n). It says its True! Note: the user0 is a value entered by the user and user0\r\n is what should have been read from the file.  So how does this happen? Does the CSV module return with line endings or not?

Comment: @Vishal "untranslated" means you get what is in the file.  If the file contains \r\n you will see \r\n when you read the file with `open`.  `csv.reader`, though, should read one line of the file and process it into a list based on the dialect settings.  For example, if the line is `a,b,c\r\n`, `csv.reader` will return `['a','b','c']`. So I'm not sure what you are talking about without an example.  Ask a new question if something is still unclear.